# How to push angular-seed project to github?

Tags: git, github, angular-seed

I have tried several times, and every time I get an error saying "permission denied from angular-seed". I don't understand this, as I never had any problems with any of my other projects. How do I get this darn project in my repo if it won't push?

Comment: Did you clone that repo? If so, why would you push it back to it? Your others projects are cloned from yourself, I assume

Comment: I used angular-seed as a base for another project for educational purposes. Now that the project is done, I cant push it to a brand new repo for my students to view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change the origin remote of your repository , for now you are pushing on the angular-seed repository itself. check it with :

```
$ git remote -v
```

change origin remote :

```
$ git remote rm origin && git remote add origin "your remote url"
```

more info here : https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote

Comment: didnt work, came back saying "No such remote: origin"

Comment: whats the output of `git remote -v` ?

Comment: output of git remote -v is my remote directory url and at the end it says (fetch)

Comment: This project has not been added to github yet so im working with a brand new repo for it. Just weird that it wont push, Ive never had any issues with any past projects except for this angular-seed project which Ill probably never use again considering all this.

Comment: i have edited my answer ( was not the branch name, but how you call the repo , in this case origin ), but you still need a remote url, when you are creating a repo on github you will have some instruction for push it remotly

Comment: now im getting errors saying "failed to push some refs" when trying to push it.

Comment: do you have already something on this repo ? seems your remote repository are not synced with your local one, did you create a readme ?

Comment: Nothing, its a brand new repo just created this morning. Nothing inside it yet.

Comment: you should try `git pull repo_name branch_name` and try to push again, if it fails then... you can still force push ( not a good pratice btw)

Comment: says that my repo does not appear to be a git repository, even though Im clearly looking at it right now in my profile. Also says "Could not read from remote repository".

Comment: you didn't register your repository with `git remote add origin repo_url` and repo_url must finish with a '.git'

Comment: Ive already done that and it comes back with "fatal: remote origin already exists"

Comment: ok so I did that with no errors. Now am I able to push or is there another step I need to take?

Comment: `git remote add origin https://github.com/garettschultz/templateStore.git` and you need to pull before push because you create a readme on the repo ( i checked it) that's why you have conflicts

Comment: then before pushing try a `git pull --rebase` and if you have some conflicts tell me

Comment: Cant pull it, when I try pulling it, it says 
$ git pull templateStore master
fatal: 'templateStore' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: `git pull origin master --rebase`

Comment: if u did `git remote add origin https://github.com/garettschultz/templateStore.git` u register it as "origin"

Comment: At this point im just utterly confused. I just want to push the dang project to github like every other project ive done in the past. Nothing seems to work properly or as it should. I should not be running into these errors when trying to do something as simple as pushing it to a repo.

Comment: :) i had these problems too at the beginning

Comment: git pull origin master --rebase came back with 
$ git pull origin master --rebase
From https://github.com/garettschultz/templateStore
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
First, rewinding head to replay your work on top of it...
Applying: adding web template store project
.git/rebase-apply/patch:107: new blank line at EOF.

Comment: ok so now try `git push origin +master` u had no errors during the previous step right ?

Comment: git push origin +master came back with "Everything is up to date"

Comment: But when I go to my github profile and refresh the page, the project isnt in there.

Comment: what if you `git status`?

Comment: git status responds with 
$ git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        app/
        node_modules/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

Comment: weird u have a .gitignore in the root of the project right ?

Comment: dont see one anywhere in the project folder, no

Comment: now this is weird, I tried pushing again and it pushed 2 files but not the whole project. Why would this happen when I told it it to push the whole master?

Comment: i have no clue for this because these files were in your .gitignore that u get from the angular seed

Comment: are there any better alternatives to git? what happened to "best tool for the job"? Seems like git is a huuuuge waste of development time.

Comment: in my opinion no, there is no better alternative , git is good for working in a team , as the repository admin you can control pull request , branches ect. But yes the first steps are not easy ( first time i f*** up my portfolio )

Comment: This isnt even my first time, Ive been using git since I graduated college in 2012 with an outdated account. Now this new account I have, its just been nothing but nightmares adding projects to repos.

Comment: maybe use a gui like gitkraken if youre not a command line guy ( no offense )

Comment: I finally got it to work, and you'd be pissed if this happened to you. It turns out it wasnt working because I never set my global username or email. After setting that, it pushed to the repo without any hesitation successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to edit the angular-seed code or make a project using it?

If the former, then you need to fork it, then clone your fork, to which you do have permission.

If the later, you shouldn't need to push to the angular-seed project, you only cloned it so you can generate a project. In that case, create and clone your own repo, then use angular seed to make a project, then you can commit and push from there

Comment: Ive already got the project completed. I used the angular-seed as a base for the project.

Comment: Yes, but since you've cloned **that** project, your `git push` command is going to **that** repository, not your own. You need to either 1) fork or 2) Change the remote repository

Comment: Ive changed the remote repository but still wont push. I keep getting this:
$ git push origin master
To 'remote url'
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'remote url'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: Ive already done that and ran into more issues. Read the comments from the above convo, you'll see what ive already tried and what hasnt worked so far. Its a really weird, unusual scenario.

Comment: Then remove the `.git` directory in that folder, and reset everything starting from here. https://help.github.com/articles/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line/